# How to show toast in second java file?

Tags: android, database-connection, toast

I have been reading this forum for days and I have found no answer to my problem.

I'm having problem with getting java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to show Toast.

In my android application I have MyWorkActivity.java which is main activity and Statistika.java intended to calculate some statistics based on data from my database.

Inside class MyWorkActivity (public class MyWorkActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener) i have menu item statistika.

When I press on that item I want to show layout Statistika.xml with data from statistika.java like this:

```
public class MyWorkActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    //Menu item statistika
    else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.statistika)
    {
        //Layout statistika.xml
         setContentView(R.layout.statistika);

         Statistika nova_statistika = new Statistika();
         nova_statistika.rsatiDanasJuceMjesec(sDatumZaPrikaz);
    }
}
```

But I have been receiving java.lang.NullPointerException on `dbJuceDanas = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseInfo.IME_BAZE, MODE_PRIVATE,null);` so I have commented database part and tried only Toast but I still get java.lang.NullPointerException.

This is my Statistika.java:

```
public class Statistika extends Activity
{
 public void rsatiDanasJuceMjesec (String sDatumZaRacunanje)
   {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Toast is working! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Računanje radnih sati za prikazani dan
//      SQLiteDatabase dbJuceDanas = null;
//      dbJuceDanas = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseInfo.IME_BAZE, MODE_PRIVATE,null);
//          
//      //Filtriranje rekordseta po datumu
//      Cursor cJuceDanas = dbJuceDanas.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseInfo.IME_TABELE + " WHERE " + DatabaseInfo.DATUM + " LIKE '%" + MyWorkActivity.sDatumZaPrikaz + "'", null);
//      
//      if (cJuceDanas !=null && cJuceDanas.getCount() > 0) 
//      {
//          //Ako postoje upisi za datum trenutnog upisa
//          int Column4 = cJuceDanas.getColumnIndex("r_vrijeme");
//
//          //Sumiranje svih radnih vremena od danas
//          fRVDanas=Float.valueOf(0);
//          do 
//          {
//              cJuceDanas.moveToFirst();
//              fRVDanas=fRVDanas+cJuceDanas.getFloat(Column4);
//          
//          }while (cJuceDanas.moveToNext());
//      }
    }
}
```

This is LogCat:

```
04-25 12:33:15.020: E/AndroidRuntime(927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 12:33:15.020: E/AndroidRuntime(927): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 12:33:15.020: E/AndroidRuntime(927):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
04-25 12:33:15.020: E/AndroidRuntime(927):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
04-25 12:33:15.020: E/AndroidRuntime(927):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
04-25 12:33:15.020: E/AndroidRuntime(927):  at myWork.amicus.ba.Statistika.rsatiDanasJuceMjesec(Statistika.java:69)
04-25 12:33:15.020: E/AndroidRuntime(927):  at myWork.amicus.ba.MyWorkActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MyWorkActivity.java:3028)
04-25 12:33:15.020: E/AndroidRuntime(927):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205)
04-25 12:33:15.020: E/AndroidRuntime(927):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:748)
```

I have tried following:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast is working! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Toast.makeText(Statistika.this, "Toast is working! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and many other combinations but it doesn't work.

As I can understand, problem is with context.

What do I need to do to be able to show Toast message and access database from Statistika.java?

Comment: Have you tried using fragments instead of switching the layout?

Comment: Y you are trying to set layout in main activity itself. You start an activity(your Statistika ) through intent and there you can set your layout..

Comment: Whether your problem solved??

Comment: I'm tying it right now.

Comment: I have moved  setContentView(R.layout.statistika); to Statistika.java inside of onCreate but I still get java.lang.NullPointerException like before. I really don't have any more ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this code

public class MyWorkActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    //Menu item statistika
    else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.statistika)
    {
        //Layout statistika.xml
         setContentView(R.layout.statistika);

         Statistika nova_statistika = new Statistika(MyWorkActivity.this);
         nova_statistika.rsatiDanasJuceMjesec(sDatumZaPrikaz);
    }
}


public class Statistika extends Activity
{

Context context;

    public Statistika(MyWorkActivity mainActivity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        context = mainActivity;
    }

 public void rsatiDanasJuceMjesec (String sDatumZaRacunanje)
   {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Toast is working! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much. Toast is working now. Only thing is that I have moved setContentView(R.layout.statistika); in to Statistika.java. So your answer have solved my problem with. I have accepted your answer. Thank you again.